# Adding in EASy86K

Tags: assembly, 68000, easy68k

I have to do a homework assignment in which the program will receive 2 numbers from the keyboard and add and multiply them, but I don’t know how. So far, I've done this:

```
  ORG    $1000
START: 
    LEA INPUT, A1               
    MOVE.B #14, D0
    TRAP #15
    
    MOVE.B #4, D0
    TRAP #15
            
    JSR SHOWNEWLINE
    
    LEA INPUT, A1              
    MOVE.B #14, D0
    TRAP #15
    
    MOVE.B #4, D0
    TRAP #15
    
    JSR SHOWNEWLINE

    ADDX D0, D0
    MOVE.B #14, D5
    TRAP #15
    
    SIMHALT
    
SHOWNEWLINE:
    LEA NEWLINE, A3
    MOVE.B #0, D1
    MOVE.B #0, D0
    TRAP #15
    RTS
    
INPUT DC.B 'Enter numbers', 0
NEWLINE DC.B ''    
  
    END START
```

It should be done in the EASy68K simulator.

Thank you!

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. You'll have an easier time getting answered if you're more specific about the problem you have.

Comment: Note that you're immediately discarding the result of [trap task 4](http://www.easy68k.com/QuickStart/TrapTasks.htm) when you call `SHOWNEWLINE` which sets `D1` to 0.

Comment: What happens when you single step in the debugger?  What is the first line that doesn't do what you want?  Then work backwards from there to figure out why...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My deadline was until midnight so I had to find a solution. Since it was not explained to us in the lecture how to use EASy86k, I tried to find help here. I hope this can help beginners.

```
    ORG    $1000
START: 
    LEA INPUT1, A1
    MOVE.B #14, D0
    MOVE.B #14, D1
    TRAP #15

    MOVE.B #4, D0
    TRAP #15

    MOVE.B D1, D2
            
    LEA INPUT2, A1 
    MOVE.B #14, D0
    MOVE.B #14, D1
    TRAP #15
              
    MOVE.B #4, D0
    TRAP #15

    MOVE.B D1, D3

    JSR SHOWNEWLINE

    LEA SUM, A1 
    MOVE.B #14, D0
    MOVE.B #14, D1
    TRAP #15

    MOVE.B D2, D4
    ADDX D3,D4
    MOVE.B D4, D1
    MOVE.B #3, D0
    TRAP #15

    JSR SHOWNEWLINE

    LEA MULTIPLICATION, A1 
    MOVE.B #14, D0
    MOVE.B #14, D1
    TRAP #15

    MOVE.B D2, D5
    MULS D3,D5
    MOVE.B D5, D1
    MOVE.B #3, D0
    TRAP #15

    SIMHALT

SHOWNEWLINE:
    LEA NEWLINE, A3
    MOVE.B #0, D1
    MOVE.B #0, D0
    TRAP #15
    RTS

INPUT1 DC.B 'Enter 1st number: ', 0
INPUT2 DC.B 'Enter 2nd number: ', 0
SUM DC.B 'Sum: ', 0
MULTIPLICATION DC.B 'Multiplication: ', 0
NEWLINE DC.B ''    

    END START
```